# Ubuntu 18.04 does not maximize => 3840x2160 resolution

Tags: multiple-monitors, ubuntu-18.04, 4k-resolution

Been trying to get 3840x2160 with my dual monitors (4k UHD Dell 27") through Displayports with lightning adapter but couldn't sort it out.

- Machine: Dell XPS 13"
- Kernel version: 4.15.0.47

Sometimes I can get it to work when i keep my laptop lid open, but most of the time I don't see an option to get 3840x2160 resolution for the both of monitors. It is like an intermittent issue.

Only resolution that I'm currently using and stable is 2048x1280 16:10, but this is not ideal as the text/fonts are quite blurry.